# How to rename xml <tag> name?

Tags: c#, html, xml, tags

I have a large xml file which have thousands of `<PARA>` tag, some `<PARA>` tag have only text like, `<PARA>HI</PARA>`,`<PARA>Stackoverflow</PARA>`,etc and some `<PARA>` tag have child tag like `<PARA><ABC>Hi</ABC></PARA>`,`<PARA><ABC>Hi</ABC></PARA>`,actually my problem is that when i am trying to read the xml file in dataset its showing error it's saying

> Cannot add constraint to DataTable 'PARA' which is a child table in
>   two nested relations.

So is there any way to rename only those `<PARA>` tags which have child tag and convert in `<A><ABC>Hi</ABC></A>`,`<A><ABC>Hi</ABC></A>` or any other idea to read this xml in dataset?
Thanks

Comment: This sounds like an [x y problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Do you really need to load this into a DataTable? It doesn't sound like the kind of structure that fits the table abstraction to me.

Comment: actually i need all  the xml data.

Comment: That's not necessarily the same thing as needing to load it into a DataSet. Perhaps take a look at LINQ to XML.